# Why is Application Record changing my RSpec Test result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

Reasonably green to testing but I was following along with a simple udemy course. I used the RSpec documentation to set up RSpec in rails to try out some testing. But I have come across an issue that for the life of me I can't figure out...

```rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  subject { described_class.new("John") }

  it "initializes a name" do
    expect(subject.name).to eq("John")
  end

  context "with no argument" do
    subject { described_class.new }

    it "should default to Bill as the name" do
      expect(subject.name).to eq("Bill")
    end
  end
end

# This is my test code. 

# This is my User model. 

class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name = "Bill")
    @name = name
  end
end
```

When I run the test it fails and says that the second test isn't returning Bill but 'nil'. However, in my User model if I remove the < Application Record it passes... Also, if I add a second parameter in the initialize, it randomly passes the default test and fails the first one returning the default name... I'm completely confused as I have been learning the testing without ApplicationRecord and that seems to be the part where it is failing. I have tried changing the subject to let(:testing){User.new} but that doesn't work. Any help seriously appreciated here as I can't seem to find it through google.

To let you know I have gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0' included in my GemFile in the :development, :test part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to override default initializer of a model and you doing it the wrong way. When you call `new` on ActiveRecord class you need to pass a hash of parameters. To have `name` field in a model you need to define it in DB schema.

Creation of an instance of `User` for the first test case should look like this:

```
described_class.new(name: "John")
```

I see these ways to have a default value for an attribute:

**Set it using a [callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :set_name

  private

  def set_name
    self.name ||= 'Bill' # Set name to Bill if it is nil
  end
end
```

**Override `initialize` method.**

```
# Please avoid this approach
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def initialize(*args)
    super # This will initiate default behaviour of a model
    self.name ||= 'Bill' 
  end
end
```

**Using [attributes API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html) as @engineersmnky suggested**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :name, :string, default: 'Bill'
end
```

**I strongly recommend using a callback or attributes API approach to not broke default behaviour.**

After that, your tests should pass I believe.

Comment: Honestly I would just remove the second option altogether. While functional this is a bad idea and is the exact reason that the callback exists in the first place so that you can avoid overriding the initialize method

Comment: Wow. Love the quick response of this site. Firstly, thank you! Interesting. So, please correct me if I'm wrong. I was still playing around with it as you answered and realised I can probably set the default in the schema as you mentioned. So I created a column again with :name but default of "Bill". I then also changed my test as you said to be written as a key, value pair and it seemed to work! Let me know if this isn't the way to do it and I should set a callback as you said above!

Comment: Another option is to use the attributes API via `attribute :name, :string, default: 'Bill'` which is probably the cleanest option [ActiveRecord Attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute)

Comment: I was also learning in a udemy course that wasn't using ActiveRecord. So I just had a model as class User. Not class User < ApplicationRecord. So I'm assuming when a schema is created that's like me having an initialize already inbuilt?

Comment: Amazing. Love all the responses. Super useful and very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for a note, I added one more example. But I'd like to keep the example with `initialize`.

Comment: "So I'm assuming when a schema is created that's like me having an initialize already inbuilt?" ActiveRecord will create attributes, getters and setters based on your schema of data. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html